# When should I create a new repo compared to developing on a fork?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have forked a project that is no longer being maintained, and have developed significantly beyond the scope of the original project. My fork is more active than the original project, but the changes will never be merged (and are not intended to be merged) back into the master branch.

Should I copy my code over to a brand new repository? Or should I continue developing on the fork? I can't tell whether forks are only for code that is supposed to be eventually merged, or for all projects that spin out of the original repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single right answer to this question.

From the user's perspective, a GitHub fork is just a clone where GitHub themselves remember some stuff for you, draw some graphs,<sup>1</sup> and arrange to make it easy to create GitHub pull requests.  If you plan never to make any pull requests and nobody has any interest in the graphs, it won't make any difference at all.

(From GitHub's perspective, they tend to like forks in that this sets up internal Git "alternates" that reduces the storage load that's otherwise required to hold both the original and the clone.  But if the fork never rejoins, this doesn't make for that much of a win in the end.)

---

<sup>1</sup>These are the contribution graphs and the like.  Some of them seem more useful to me than others.

Comment: I think I like thinking of my project as a spin-off of the original, and I think I get some traffic from the original. Maybe down the line if it gets big I will move it, but it does seem like there's no need.